# HTTPS warning: works on desktop, warning on mobile

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, https, iis-6

I installed a wildcard SSL certificate (*.vht.com) for my work and accessing the following website in chrome (or any desktop browser) https://tours.vht.com/fsviewer3/fss2.html works, but when trying to access using iOS or android(chrome) you will get warnings about the certificate not being valid (also getting warning about insecure content). 
Any ideas on why?
more info: I'm running IIS6 on that server.

Comment: beautiful house! is this phoenix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add the intermediate certificate into the IIS SSL configuration. For details see: https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4875/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-5-6

You can test if the intermediate certificate is provided by IIS with: `echo ""| openssl s_client -showcerts -connect tours.vht.com:443`

The intermediate certificate you need to install in IIS is " Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2" listed bellow:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 11):

You're most likely missing the intermediate GoDaddy certificates on your server. Most desktop browsers cache these, but I don't think mobile ones do.

Check the [GoDaddy Article](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/868/what-is-an-intermediate-certificate) on intermediate certificates with full instructions on acquiring and installing the ones from them.

Generally, certificates come as a "chain". The top Certificate Authority does not directly sign your server's certificate. Instead, there is a hierarchy of intermediate authorities that sign down the line until your server is signed.

When you receive a certificate back from an issuer, they should give you more than just the response to the certificate request file. Additionally, they should provide the intermediate certificates that also need to be installed.

Comment: :) I guess I could've clicked the valid link to see who issued it huh?

Comment: +1, you're correct. [See this check](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=tours.vht.com) which tells us *Chain issues: Incomplete* - as well as other issues.